# Email form data in rails without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, actionmailer

I have a form that I've created to capture simple contact information from a user:

**views/whitepapers/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag({action: "download"}, id: "whitepaper-form-#{w.id}") do %>
  <%= label_tag 'name' %>
  <%= text_field_tag "contact[name]", nil, class: "form-control" %>
  <br/>
  <%= label_tag 'email' %>
  <%= email_field_tag "contact[email]", nil, class: "form-control" %>
  <br/>
  <%= label_tag 'phone' %>
  <%= text_field_tag "contact[phone]", nil, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag 'id', w.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'whitepaper-name', w.title %>
  <%= submit_tag "Download Now", class: "btn btn-success", id: "whitepaper-#     {w.id}-submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Now, Once the user clicks the "Download" button, the file downloads, so I have that part taken care of.  Now I'd like to email the form data *without* saving anything to the DB.

I've created the mailer: **mailers/whitepaper_download_mailer.rb**

```
class WhitepaperDownloadMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def email_lead(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail to: "admin@example.co", subject: "A Whitepaper Download!"
  end
end
```

And I've started working on implementing in the controller, but all the examples I've run across have to do with data including the model.  This is what I have so far, but it's not working in my controller:

**controllers/whitepapers.rb**

```
def download
@whitepaper = Whitepaper.find(params[:id])
@contact.name = params[:contact_name]
@contact.email = params[:contact_email]
@contact.phone = params[:contact_phone]
@contact.whitepaper_name = params[:whitepaper_name] 
file_path = File.join(Rails.root, "public", @whitepaper.whitepaper_url)
send_file file_path

WhitepaperDownloadMailer.email_lead(@contact).deliver_now
```

end

**models/whitepaper.rb**

```
class Whitepaper < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :whitepaper, WhitepaperUploader

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :abstract, presence: true
  validates :whitepaper, presence: true
end
```

Obviously, I know this isn't going to work since I'm passing @contact to the mailer, but pulling form params into a structure (i.e. @contact.name).  Should I be passing each of the parameter variables into the mailer:

```
WhitepaperDownloadMailer.email_lead(@contact.name, @contact.email, @contact.phone).deliver_now
```

Or is there some other way that I haven't found yet to make this mailer work?

Comment: Can you show your whitepaper model?  Or is the point that you don't have one?  You can create `class Whitepaper` and then use `include ActiveModel::Model` rather than inheriting from `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: I don't think you're too far off. Your mailer looks just fine, but I have a feeling your issue is in the attribute assignment inside of your controller.

Where you're assigning values to the `@contact` variable, does that object exist? Secondly, are your param keys correct? Is the parameter `params[:contact][:name]` instead of `params[:contact_name]`?

Comment: @steveklein updated with whitepaper model

Comment: @kevinthompson I believe the parameters are correct.  I'm basing off the `name=""` field

Comment: @kevinthompson I think that's where my problem is... is there a way to pull params from a form into an object that isn't related to a model?

Comment: @Godzilla74 A "model" is just a Ruby object. You could create a new class saved somewhere in your application that can accept and store those values, but the easiest solution might be to use an OpenStruct, which is a class that can accept a hash of data and provides accessors for that data. `@contact = OpenStruct.new(params[:contact])` would be all you would need.

Comment: So, in keeping with what I need to do: `@contact = Openstruct.new(name: params[:contact_name], email: params[:contact_email], phone: params[:contact_phone], whitepaper_name: params[:whitepaper_name])` should work?  However, I get the error `uninitialized constant WhitepapersController::Openstruct`

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out with help from @kevinthompson and Openstruct.  So, directly from the form, in my controller **controllers/whitepapers.rb**:

```
def contact
  @whitepaper = Whitepaper.find(params[:contact][:whitepaper_id])
  file_path = File.join(Rails.root, "public", @whitepaper.whitepaper_url)
  send_file file_path

  if request.post?
    @contact = OpenStruct.new(params[:contact])
    WhitepaperDownloadMailer.email_lead(@contact).deliver_now
  end
end
```

I also ended up changing the form_tag action in the view to coincide:

```
<%= form_tag({action: "contact"}, id: "whitepaper-form-#{w.id}") do %>
```